# howler.js - button fade in and fade out music in class change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, howler.js

Hello i need help with howler.js http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library

i make website and in this site it's a small image

And this work fine music it's fadeout

```
$(function(){
sh_highlightDocument();

$('.ex2-fadein').on('click', function(){
    sound2.pause().fadeIn(0.5, 2000);
});
$('.ex2-fadeout').on('click', function(){
    sound2.fadeOut(0, 3700);
});
```

but if i click to fadein this same icon this is not working.

Please tell me how to change class in this icon from

```
<div id="musicoffon" class="ex2-fadeout"><img src="images/music.png"></div>
```

to

```
 <div id="musicoffon" class="ex2-fadein"><img src="images/music.png"></div>
```

after i click?

Thanks for any help. i really search answer 6 hours :(

Comment: Any possibility you could provide a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for us to investigate?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confused with your code. It is very simple. You can create a class with opacity property and then toggle the class when you click on the div "musicoffon". One remainder, you need to use jquery UI for this.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="musicoffon" class="ex2-fadeout"><img src="http://www.detailinggurus.com/images/sample_bottles.jpg"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .ex2-fadein
{
 opacity:0.6;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#musicoffon').on('click', function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('ex2-fadein',500);
    });
});
```

[**Have a Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G3GTY/1/)